# Connect SQL server to Unix shell programming

Tags: sql, unix, scripting, sybase, connectivity

I am migrating from Sybase DB to SQL server DB. Previously Sybase was connected as:

```
SYBASE=/usr/local/sybase; export SYBASE
```

How to replace it with SQL Server ?

Comment: what do you mean by 'replace it'? are you talking about replacing the RDBMS (ie, how to replace Sybase with SQL Server)? are you talking about replacing the Sybase client software?  it's unclear what you're requesting assistance with ...

Comment: Replacing means need to use SQL server DB instead of Sybase DB

Comment: if you're asking this group for instructions on how to replace Sybase with SQL Server ... that's beyond the scope of what we can help with in this medium; you can't just update an environment variable and, poof, you're converted;